# Why is this knockout array not updating in the DOM?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

JS from my viewModel:

```
 self.newInterests = ko.observableArray();

 self.saveNewInterest = function () {
    // construct data and send to server
    var payload = {
        // data defined here
    };
    var appendInterest = function(newInterest) {
        self.newInterests().push(newInterest);
    };
    interestservice().addInterest(payload, appendInterest);
    self.closeModal();
 };
```

interestservice.addInterest:

```
var addInterest = function (payload, callback) {
    loadAnimate();
    var options = {
        url: apiEndpoint + 'interest',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: payload,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    };
    return $.ajax(options)
        .done(function (response) {
            toastr.success("Interest Added", "Success");
            callback(response);
        })
        .fail(function (msg) {
            toastr.error("Could not add interest.", "Error");
        }).complete(function () {
            loadComplete();
        });
};
```

in my view:

```
<h3 data-bind="text: newInterests().length"></h3>
<div data-bind="foreach: newInterests()">
    <p>new interest!</p>
</div>
```

If I init the newInterests() array with data, it shows up in the DOM.  If I debug, I see the data from the server getting added to the array, but the view's bindings aren't being updated for some reason.  Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the () from newInterests and it will update properly.

```
<h3 data-bind="text: newInterests().length"></h3>
<div data-bind="foreach: newInterests">
    <p>new interest!</p>
</div>
```

Also when you push a value you don't need to get it first -

```
var appendInterest = function(newInterest) {
    self.newInterests.push(newInterest);
};
```

Comment: perfect.  These parentheses are killin me!  Thanks for the help

Comment: There are a few rules - in the view Knockout unwraps the observable already for you (as long as it is the last on the function chain) - ie. this().you().hey and when you want to pass the object you use parans, when you want to pass the value use the ().  Good luck